# Execution Context of Methods in Go vs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, go

Below are two code snippets - one in Go and the other in JavaScript - essentially doing the same thing.

// **Go**

```
package main    

import "fmt"

type Engine struct {
  bootTimeInSecs int
}

func (e *Engine) Start() {
  fmt.Printf("Engine starting in %s seconds ...", e.bootTimeInSecs)
}

type Start func() 

type BenchmarkSuite struct {
  workloads []string
  start Start 
}

func main() {
  engine := Engine{10}
  benchmarkSuite := BenchmarkSuite{workloads: []string{}, start: engine.Start}
  benchmarkSuite.start()
}
```

**Output**

```
Engine starting in 10 seconds ...
```

// **JavaScript**

```
function Engine(bootTimeInSecs) {
    this.bootTimeInSecs = bootTimeInSecs
}

Engine.prototype.constructor = Engine
Engine.prototype.Start = function() {
  console.log("Engine starting in " + this.bootTimeInSecs + " seconds ...")
}

function BenchmarkSuite(workloads, start) {
    this.workloads = workloads
    this.start = start
} 

BenchmarkSuite.prototype.constructor = BenchmarkSuite

engine = new Engine(10)
benchmarkSuite = new BenchmarkSuite([], engine.Start)
benchmarkSuite.start()
```

**Output**

```
Engine starting in undefined seconds ...
```

I know the workaround in JavaScript, but that's not the question. Why did JavaScript decide not to **retain** the *original* execution context of a function?

Comment: Whoever gave a `close` vote on the question, can you explain how the question would attract **opinion** based answers?

Comment: please check the answer , you forgot to bind the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in javascript the function is not bind to the object `engine` when you pass the object to `BenchmarkSuite` constructor.

You have to explicitly bind the object to the function. 
This is what you have to do

```
benchmarkSuite = new BenchmarkSuite([], engine.Start.bind(engine))
```

> The simplest use of bind() is to make a function that, no matter how it is called, is called with a particular this value. A common mistake for new JavaScript programmers is to extract a method from an object, then to later call that function and expect it to use the original object as its this (e.g. by using that method in callback-based code). Without special care however, the original object is usually lost. Creating a bound function from the function, using the original object, neatly solves this problem

You may refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more

```js
function Engine(bootTimeInSecs) {
    this.bootTimeInSecs = bootTimeInSecs
}

Engine.prototype.constructor = Engine
Engine.prototype.Start = function() {
  console.log("Engine starting in " + this.bootTimeInSecs + " seconds ...")
}

function BenchmarkSuite(workloads, start) {
    this.workloads = workloads
    this.start = start
} 

BenchmarkSuite.prototype.constructor = BenchmarkSuite

engine = new Engine(10)
benchmarkSuite = new BenchmarkSuite([], engine.Start.bind(engine))
benchmarkSuite.start()
```

Comment: @bharat-khatri  please check and upvote the answer if it helped you :D